# Unity3D: Move the parent gameobject relative to the child

Tags: unity, c#, mathematics, vector, gameobject

[image]

So, I have `X and Y game objects`. I have a vector `Z = X - Y` which is indicated by the green line.

Also, I have a `Parent` game object and it has a `Child` game object. How do I move the parent such that the child game object is at the `Point Y`

I tried,

```
                  Z -= new Vector3(child.localPosition.x, 0, child.localPosition.z);
                  Parent.transform.position = Z
```

which is not working as expected.
Thank you!

Comment: What does Z have to do with all of this? Just add `Y - C.transform.position` to the parent's position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try something like this?

```
childToTarget = targetPosition - child.position;
childToTarget.y = 0;

parent.position+= childToTarget;
```